# How can I query MIUI specific application permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, xiaomi, miui

My application adds pinned shortcut to home screen.
It does it using ShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(...) call since I target devices with 26+ API.
It works fine for various devices except Xiaomi which features "AppInfo/Other permissions" with "Home Screen Shortcut" turned off.
When I try to call requestPinShortcut logcat says that my application doesn't have permission but doesn't specify its name.
I can't figure out how can I check if this permission.
Does anybody know the name of this permission and how one can query its value programmatically?
[Here I attach MIUI application settings activity view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZzJH.png)

I tried to debug at the call point but with no luck.